Gas estimation error when interacting with smart contract
I wrote a simple smart contract for bulk sending eth to multiple addresses on Remix
pragma solidity ^0.4.21;

contract PayMultiple {
    function pay(address[] payees, uint values) public payable{
        for(uint i = 0; i < payees.length; i++){
            payees[i].transfer(values);
        }
    }   
}

The deployment went well (Sepolia Etherscan)
When I try to execute the pay function, along with the some random address, with random value to send
["0xAb8483F64d9C6d1EcF9b849Ae677dD3315835cb2", "0x4B20993Bc481177ec7E8f571ceCaE8A9e22C02db"]
10000000000000

, Remix pops up this error, and when I chose to keep doing the transaction, it will eventually be failed (Sepolia Etherscan)
Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?
Error happened while trying to execute a function inside a smart contract

What should I do to fix this problem?

Make sure that you're passing the sufficient value to cover the transfer for all the payees. So, in your case the value should be 20000000000000 Wei.
If you're using Remix IDE, then you can pass the value from the left menu under Deploy & run transactions tab like this:


You can also put a check for that using the require function, like:
require(msg.value == values * payees.length);

Also, you're using quite older solidity compiler version, so it's recommended to use something newer like 0.8.24 or so. The revised code using ^0.8.24 would be:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.24;

contract PayMultiple {

    function pay(address[] memory payees, uint values) public payable{

        require(msg.value == values * payees.length, "Passed value is not sufficient for payment");

        for(uint i = 0; i < payees.length; i++){
            payable(payees[i]).transfer(values);
        }
    }   
}

The compiler version can be selected from the Remix IDE using the left menu under Solidity compiler tab like this:

